# YouTube video posting to wrong Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I have two Facebook pages. One is my personal page and another is my blog. All my videos are posting to my personal page. How can I change that to posting on my blog's Facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here posting YouTube video means you are sharing a video from YouTube to Facebook. If my guess is correct, here is the steps to share a video from YouTube to Facebook:

- Open a video on YouTube.
- Click on Share icon.
- Select Facebook.
- If you are already login it redirect to your wall and show a dropdown `Share on your own Timeline`.
- Change `Share on your own Timeline` to `Share on a page you manage`.
- Just downside of above dropdown menu, there will be another dropdown menu with all the page names which you manage.
- Select any page on which you want share video and click on `Post to Facebook`.

Other case is if you are direct posting a link of video (or a video) on wall, make sure you are acting as "your blog's page" instead of "your account".